# filter products by attribute dropdown option value with category id in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to filter product by attribute drop-down option value with category id. I am using following query to filter but not working?

```
$collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$options = Mage::getModel('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'city')
    ->getSource()
    ->getAllOptions(); //get all options

$optionId = false;
foreach ($options as $option) {
    if (strtolower($option['label']) == 'delhi') { option
        $optionId = $option['value'];
        break;
    }
}

if ($optionId) { 
    $collection1->addAttributeToFilter('city', $optionId);
}

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(49);
$collection1->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong in this query?

Comment: Just formatted your code for you - I left `option` on the first if statement line, I assume it's a typo but you never know.

Comment: check the sql query result by (string)$collection1->getSelect();

Comment: Pankaj- is "city" a custom attribute? Are you using flat tables? If both is yes, chances are that your attribute isn't available in the product collection to be able to filter it - plenty of related questions e.g. "filter collection by custom attribute"

Comment: yes i used a custom attribute with flat table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried like this?

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(49);
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addCategoryFilter($category) 
    ->addAttributeToFilter('city',
        array('finset' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
            ->getAttribute('city')
            ->getSource()
            ->getOptionId('delhi')
        )
    )
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```